# I need portable backup system

Tags: backup

I need some backup system that will snapshot my stuff to a dedicated external drive, that will work with both OSX and Linux (Windows support nice but not essential).

Where should I look?

Answer (score 3):

[CrashPlan](http://b4.crashplan.com/consumer/index.html) will probably do that.

Answer (score 0):

I use [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/). You can choose which cloud backend you want, and it supports many OSs. (And it's very cheap!)

Proof:

[image]

(Portable is also avaliable as you can see.)

Comment: I like the exclamation mark after "No spyware, bundles or ads included"! Windows is an amazing ecosystem.

Comment: Yeah, that's a feature nowadays.